# Element 'block', attribute 'ifConfig': The attribute 'ifConfig' is not allowed

Tags: magento2

I have transferred my magento website to another server now I am getting below error

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'ifConfig': The attribute 'ifConfig' is not allowed.
Line: 205
```

And my magento version is 2.2.3

I am stuck here from few days. So please help to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you resolve this?
I have the same on 2.2.4 - I have no idea what changed on my site, it was fine when I left it last week and now this.
I've changed to a default Magento theme, but the issue still persists.

Update: I've found my problem, it was in an XML file in an extension. No idea why it suddenly became problematic, unfortunately. The only way I found it was to do a case-sensitive search on ifConfig on all of the files

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the error messaging you are trying to use "ifConfig" rather than "ifconfig". I hope this helps!